# completely remove a git submodule which is causing a fatal error after repo rename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-submodules, formwizard

I have an old project (RAILS) I'm trying to get up and running again. I (probably stupidly, but too late now) renamed the repo for various reasons (using gem 'rename' + changing github..etc).

There appears to be a submodule attached to the project, (related to a minor change that was hacked onto formwizard) that is refusing to play ball. I've tried just about every approach I can find, but I just can't get rid of it.

Currently if I try `git submodule init` I get:

```
    No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'public/javascripts/formwizard'
```

In order to get that far I had to clone an old version of the repo to it's original position.

Otherwise I get

```
    fatal: Not a git repository at $path_inc_old_project_name
```

I just want this thing to go away and stop being linked to my main repo. Nothing i do seems to work

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule) solution fails as `submodule deinit` isn't recognised (have upgraded to latest install of git using homebrew).

`git rm --cached path_to_submodule`

Just returns

`fatal: 'path_to_submodule' is outside repository`
i.e. the path you need is outside the repository

I know that, that's why I'm trying to get rid of the damn thing...

I've tried removing every reference to the old project name with a find replace, but the git repo still seems to know where to look for this submodule.

How can I tell git to just forget about this submodule...? (or in fact, all submodules as this is the only one I have)

Comment: Doesn't editing `.gitmodule` and doing a subsequent `git submodule update --recursive --init` help?